# How to create a viewport according to the screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this little fun project, it is a button which can't be clicked. So basically what I want is that the entire thing fits on the screen, but it is not fitting the full screen, it is just in the top-left.

How can I make it the size of my screen and center it in the middle. Also the button should also move in the whole screen.

```js
$(".block").mouseover(function() {
  $(".block").animate({
    left: (Math.random() * 650),
    top: (Math.random() * 450),
  }, "fast");
});
```

```css
.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 700;
  height: 500;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: purple;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="block">
    <button type="button" class="button">Catch me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Min-width: 100vw; min-height: 100vh; Position: absolute; on the Element you want to span 100% of the screen

Comment: its a little too big and also the button should move everywhere aswell can you suggest something.

Comment: Stick to one question at the time and be clear about what you want.

Comment: Actually I mentioned it in the description as well. i want the button to move to fullest as well. sorry btw but can you do something about that button? i figured out the main diiv

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will works:

```
.main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: actually can you do something about button aswell its only moving in that particular area it should move everywhere

Comment: also its covered the whole screen but its little too big now

Answer (score 0):

You would have to try this more but I took the full width and height of the `document`, it moves more but it might move outside of the browser so you need to validate that. I also changed the css for your block, now you have padding instead of a height and width, the height and width was actually smaller then the button.

```js
$(".block").mouseover(function() {
  $(".block").animate({
    left: (Math.random() * $(document).width()),
    top: (Math.random() * $(document).height()),
  }, "fast");
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.moving-element {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: purple;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="block">
    <button type="button" class="moving-element">Catch me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```